# Copy documents to a subsites

Tags: document-library, rest, copy-item

I have a site collection `MySiteCollection` which contains many subsites like `SiteA`, `SiteB`, `SiteC`, etc. 
Each subsite contains its own subsites. For example `SiteA-1`, `SiteA-2`, `SiteA-3`.

And I want to copy a document from a library in the root site of `MySiteCollection` to a subsite like `SiteA-3` with REST API.

I found some examples, but they don't work for me. So if you have a solution for this problem, I would be glad if you can post it.

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint REST API contains [SP.File.copyTo Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247198(v=office.15).aspx):

**Endpoint URI**

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/folders/getbyurl(folderrelativeurl)/files/getbyurl(filerelativeurl)/copyTo(strNewUrl,bOverWrite)
```

for copying the file to the destination URL , but **it is supported** to copy files **within a same site** only, for example:

```
function copyTo(sourceFileUrl,targetFileUrl, success,error)
{
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + sourceFileUrl + "')/copyto(strnewurl='" + targetFileUrl + "',boverwrite=false)"; 
    return $.ajax({
            url: endpointUrl,
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {   
             "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            }, 
        });
}
```

Usage

```
copyTo('/site/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx','Documents/SharePoint User Guide 2013.docx')
   .done(function(data){
       console.log('File has been copied successfully');    
   })
   .fail(function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
```

---

To copy files *between sites* using REST API you could consider the following approach:

- retrieve a source file content using
  `/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<sourcefileurl>')/$value` endpoint
- upload a file to target location using  `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<targetfolderurl>')/Files/Add(url='filename',overwrite=true)` endpoint

Follow an article [How to copy files between sites using JavaScript REST in Office365 / SharePoint 2013](http://techmikael.blogspot.fi/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html) for a complete solution.

Comment: +1, {@Vadim}, how can one get around the issue of having long urls in case of `SP.File.copyTo Method`.?

Comment: Regarding the issue of having long url, one option to shorten endpoint url would be to specify site relative url for  copyTo method (see the 'Usage' section in the updated answer)

Comment: {@Vadim}, is there any way of specifying this in the request body? I ask this because I believe `CopyTo` can be used to copy files to sub sites in the same site. What if there are many levels of nested sub sites and url passes the 256 character limit.

Comment: Thanks @VadimGremyachev ! I was struggling a lot with this, now I used your code and it finally works! By the way, is it possible to get back the ID of the new copied document?

Comment: @NadeemYousuf, did you find any solution for 256 character limit? i m facing same issue

Comment: @AnilD, no I didn't find any solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution which copy the document for me.

```
$.ajax({
            url: currentSiteUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + sourceFileRef + "')/$value",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            binaryStringResponseBody: true
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result=== null) {
                console.error("Data is null");
                dfd.reject();
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: targetUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + targetFileRef + "')/files/add(url='" + newFileName + "')",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": _REQUESTDIGEST
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                    data: result,
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log("Document copied.");

                }).fail(function (data) {
                    console.error("Document copy failed.");
                    console.log(data);
                    console.trace();
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.error("Document can not be found.");
            console.log(data);
            console.trace();
        });
```

Now I have a new problem. My copied document is **empty**. So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have been struggling with this a few times

1. CopyTo only works within a site and removes all version history.
2. Using Rest and downloading the content as binary data crashes the browser for files larger than 40 MB.

SPServices! This oldie using Copy.asmx seems to work (also in SP Online) to copy files between different sites and with large files:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CopyIntoItemsLocal&referringTitle=Copy